# Intersecting text files by its location from a list

Tags: awk

I need to intersect the a file from a list of locations as like this

File 1

```
cat02 2 5
cat02 2 3
cat03 2 3
```

File2

```
cat02 1 xxx xxx
cat02 2 xxx sss www
cat02 3 swe ede rrr
cat02 4 aqw ede efd
cat02 5 aws ede as
cat02 6 aqw
cat03 1 aaa
cat03 2 wer
cat03 3 ddddd
```

expected output

```
cat02 2 xxx sss www
cat02 3 swe ede rrr
cat02 4 aqw ede efd
cat02 5 aws ede as
cat02 2 xxx sss www
cat02 3 swe ede rrr
cat03 2 wer
cat03 3 ddddd
```

For this purpose I used this code

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
start[$1]=$2
till[$1]=$3
next}$2>=start[$1] && $2<=till[$1]' File1 File2
```

But if I am trying to grep two ranges for cat02 I only get the output for the last range read instead of both ranges:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{
start[$1]=$2
till[$1]=$3
next}$2>=start[$1] && $2<=till[$1]' file1 file2
cat02 2 xxx sss www
cat02 3 swe ede rrr
cat03 2 wer
cat03 3 ddddd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    vals[$1,$2] = $0
    next
}
{
    for (i=$2; i<=$3; i++) {
        key = ($1 SUBSEP i)
        if (key in vals) {
            print vals[key]
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk File2 File1
cat02 2 xxx sss www
cat02 3 swe ede rrr
cat02 4 aqw ede efd
cat02 5 aws ede as
cat02 2 xxx sss www
cat02 3 swe ede rrr
cat03 2 wer
cat03 3 ddddd
```

Comment: Simply I need all the location from the File1 and problem was If I am using this command it will skip the first one. You are right I need both

Comment: OK, I just added an answer. If that's not what you're looking for then please update your question to include in the example cases that this doesn't work for. Note the order of the file arguments - File2 gets read first. I also updated your question to state what I now think your problem was, fix that if I got it wrong or if you think it can be phrased better too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {s[$1]=$2;e[$1]=$3;next} 
                $2>=s[$1] && $2<=e[$1]' file1 file2

cat02 2 xxx sss www
cat02 3 swe ede rrr
cat02 4 aqw ede efd
cat02 5 aws ede as
cat03 2 wer
cat03 3 ddddd
```

actually it's the identical code with yours, perhaps your line endings is a problem.  You can see with `cat -A file`.