# Add character on missing position while intersecting

Tags: awk

I just have two files as like this and I just want to extract positions based on the file 1, If positions is not found in file 2 add N on the missing positions.I have seen @user90 ([Intersecting text files by its location from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62349346/intersecting-text-files-by-its-location-from-a-list)) asked how to intersect and I just used the same Examples.I tried with the solutions mentioned on that question and tried to print empty line when position missing and replace blank space with N using sed.

File 1

```
cat02 2 5
cat02 2 3
cat03 1 3
```

File2

```
 cat02 1 xxx xxx
 cat02 2 xxx sss www
 cat02 3 swe ede rrr
 cat02 5 aws ede as
 cat02 6 aqw
 cat03 2 wer
 cat03 3 ddddd
```

expected output

```
 cat02 2 xxx sss www
 cat02 3 swe ede rrr
 cat02 4 N   N    N
 cat02 5 aws ede as
 cat02 2 xxx sss www
 cat02 3 swe ede rrr
 cat03 1 N    N   N
 cat03 2 wer
 cat03 3 ddddd
```

Comment: Please also add what you tried, and explain in more details what you want....   How can 3 lines in file1, and 7 line in file2 become 9 lines in expected output?

Comment: `it did not work` is the worst possible problem statement, If you want help you have to tell us in what way it didn't work - wrong output, no output, syntax error, other error messages, core dumps, something else....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy to do with a slight variation of the accepted answer of that other question:

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f
NR==FNR {
    vals[$1,$2] = $0
    next
}
{
    for (i=$2; i<=$3; i++) {
        key = ($1 SUBSEP i)
        if (key in vals) {
            print vals[key]
        } else {
            print $1, i, "N", "N", "N"
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
$ awk -f demo.awk file2 file1
cat02 2 xxx sss www
cat02 3 swe ede rrr
cat02 4 N N N
cat02 5 aws ede as
cat02 2 xxx sss www
cat02 3 swe ede rrr
cat03 1 N N N
cat03 2 wer
cat03 3 ddddd
```

Answer (score 1):

this is like solving a puzzle, can be simplified further

```
$ join -t$'\t' -a1 <(awk '{for(i=$2;i<=$3;i++) print $1"_"i "\t" NR "\t" $1,i}' file1 | sort) \
                   <(awk '{print $1 "_" $2 "\t" $3,$4,$5}' file2) | 
  sort -k2 | cut -f3- | awk 'NF==2{$3=$4=$5="N"}1'

cat02 2 xxx sss www
cat02 3 swe ede rrr
cat02 4 N N N
cat02 5 aws ede as
cat02 2 xxx sss www
cat02 3 swe ede rrr
cat03 1 N N N
cat03 2 wer
cat03 3 ddddd
```

expands the first file for record keys, creates a synthetic key to join on and to preserve the initial order to survive sorting, removes it after and add the missing value substitutes